# What is the difference between tf.scatter_update and tf.scatter_nd_update?

Tags: python, tensorflow

From the documentation I can tell they differ for example in the way they handle the arguments.

However, it's not clear to me when it's appropriate to use one over the other. (and similarly for the other `scatter(_nd)_foo` operations.)

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_update

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_nd_update